# Why am I getting an error near semi colon (:)?

Tags: t-sql

I have no idea but this is throwing an error i think it is on line "set @al = 2020". I have read the documentation and not seeming to translate over.

```
begin
declare @al int;
set @al = 2020;

exec dbo.get_egus_trdg_desk_rpt_no_clrg_broker(@al int);
end
```

Error message:

> SQL Error [102] [42000]: Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Sybase and SQL Server are different products (that both use the T-SQL dialect of SQL) What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: The syntax for executing a stored procedure is `EXEC proc @arg1 = ..., @arg2 = ...`. No parentheses, as no expression are allowed. For a table-valued function, it's `SELECT * FROM func(value, value, value)`, and then parentheses are mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use ';' after every line of code. I can successfully generate the following script in SQL Server 2019.
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSo0T.png)

Comment: From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version." Make it a habit to use it.

Comment: Rather than providing a link to an image of a query that represents a fraction of the OP's code, it would be more helpful to provide a link to a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the complete solution. And, of course, include the code in your answer against the possibility of dbfiddle vanishing.

Comment: Thanks @HABO. I really appreciate your reply. I will try to implement your strategy next time.